# inbound-channel-adapter - How to update row field on failure?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jdbc

I have an integration that starts with a standard database query and it update the state in the database to indicate that the integration has worked fine. It works.

But if the data cannot be processed and an exception is raised, the state is not updated as intended, but I would like to update my database row with a 'KO' state so the same row won't fail over and over.

Is there a way to provide a second query to execute when integration fails?

It seems to me that it is very standard way of doing things but I couldn't find a simple way to do it. I could catch exception in every step of the integration and update the database, but it creates coupling, so there should be another solution.

I tried a lot of Google search but I could not find anything, but I'm pretty sure the answer is out there.

Just in case, there is my xml configuration to do the database query (nothing fancy) :

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter auto-startup="true" data-source="datasource"
            query="select * FROM MyTable  where STATE='ToProcess')"
            channel="stuffTransformerChannel"
            update="UPDATE MyTable SET STATE='OK' where id in (:id)"
            row-mapper="myRowMapper" max-rows-per-poll="1">
            <int:poller fixed-rate="1000">
                <int:transactional />
            </int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I'm using spring-integration version 4.0.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 2):

Since you are within Transaction, it is normal behaviuor, that rallback is caused and your DB returns to the clear state.

And it is classical pattern to get the deal with data on application purpose in that case, not from some built-in tool. That's why we don't provide any `on-error-update`, because it can't be a use-case for evrything.

As soon as you are going to update the row anyway you should do something on `onRallback` event and do it within new transaction, though. However it should be in the same Thread, to prevent fetching the same row from the second polling task.

For this purpose we provide a `transaction-synchronization-factory` feature:

```xml
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter max-rows-per-poll="1">
      <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="1">
           <int:transactional synchronization-factory="syncFactory"/>
      </int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="syncFactory">
     <int:after-rollback channel="stuffErrorChannel"/>
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>

<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter 
        query="UPDATE MyTable SET STATE='KO' where id in (:payload[id])"
        channel="stuffErrorChannel">
    <int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
         <tx:advice id="requiresNewTx">
             <tx:attributes>
                 <tx:method name="handle*Message" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW"/>
             </tx:attributes>
         </tx:advice>           
    </int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Hope I am clear

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, yes you are clear. I set this up but it seems that the parameter is not kept between the inbound-channel-adapter and the outbound-channel adapter. in debug mode in NamedParameterUtils#buildValueArray method the parameter paramSource contains an empty map.

Comment: OK. Wouldn't you mind to debug `JdbcMessageHandler#handleMessageInternal` and take a look, how message looks for `
<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>` ? Sorry, no chance to check it from code. However maybe you should use `:payload[id]`, because the root object in that case is `Message`, not its `payload`, as it is in update for `inbound-adapter`?

Comment: I don't mind help you helping me. :D In the message I do have the bean that comes out from the rowMapper, it does contain the correct values.

Comment: Good. Then I was right. So, just resort your `update` exression to use correct values from that `payload`. I've updated my answer to show `(:payload[id])`

Comment: Yes, we are almost there, I had to use :payload[0]. I do have an object in the array but it seems not to be in the right type, I have a Invalid column type.  My java field is int and the column is of type NUMBER (oracle).

Comment: Can your `myRowMapper` provide more friendlier object as result? Seems for me `Integer` will be converted to the `NUMBER` perfectly.

Comment: Just tried that with no success. I had tried with BigInteger before with no success either. BigInteger seems to be the type that squirrel is using to map to number. The weird thing is that the type is correct when the integration doesn't fail. I puzzles me.

Comment: M-m-m. How about `Long` ?

Comment: Long doesn't work better. You have an idea why the type works with one query and not the other?